# Apple Watch .png images loading in simulator but not on device for Apple

Tags: ios, objective-c, apple-watch

Apple have rejected a binary for app with Apple Watch app for images not loading on start up.  Works fine on simulator, case sensitivity on naming of `.png` checked.

Image target menbership boxes checked for `myApp`, `myAppwatcKitExtension` and `myAppwatckitApp`.

What hoop have I not jumped through?

Comment: Try this answer? http://stackoverflow.com/a/29631755/4246760

Comment: I had been worried they'd do this: reject apps because they fail on a device we can't yet test on. I imagine I'll be in the same predicament in a few days' time...

Comment: @DanialG thanks, looks promising! @ Echelon, yep a ridiculous situation, steps to reproduce "start the app on a device" - unebelivable